# useState not working inside mapping function

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui

```
const brands = [
  { key: 1, name: "Chanel" },
  { key: 2, name: "louis Vuitton" },
  { key: 3, name: "Gucci" },
  { key: 4, name: "Dior" },
];
```

```
const [brandName, setBrandName] = useState("");
```

```
{brands.map((items) => (
        <ButtonBase
          onClick={() => {
            setBrandSelected(!brandSelected);
            console.log(items.name);
            setBrandName(items.name);
            console.log(brandName);
          }}
          key={items.key}
          sx={{ width: "100%", mt: "1%", height: "20%" }}
        >
          <MDBox
            display="flex"
            flexDirection="row"
            width="100%"
            height="100%"
            alignItems="center"
            justifyContent="flex-start"
            sx={{
              backgroundColor: "#ffffff",
              "&:hover": {
                backgroundColor: "#f5ede9",
              },
              pl: "4%",
            }}
          >
            <MDTypography>{items.name}</MDTypography>
          </MDBox>
        </ButtonBase>
      ))}
```

I have rendered a list of brand names using array.map function and wrap it inside a button. I intend to save the brand name whenever a user clicks the button. First button = Chanel, second button = Louis Vuitton, and so on into the "brandName" variable.

I'm having trouble updating "brandName" using useState function inside the array.map function. It returns an empty string whenever I console log "brandName" after using setBrandName(items.name). However, the correct data is printed if I just do console.log(items.name). What am I missing here? Any ideas?

Comment: Hmm, that's weird, on first glance it looks fine. Can you include a bit more code, that shows how your functional component is set up?

Comment: It's just a silly mistake, there's nothing wrong with the code. Look at ZomitaKa explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have done nothing wrong , this 'problem' happened to many people and they are really thinking there is something worng and the simple answer is **ReactJs useState sets its state asynchronously** which means the next line which is the `console.log()` will probably print the value before changing
so to verify the value of `brandName` do it in a `useEffect`

```
useEffect(()=>{
   console.log(brandName)
},[brandName])
```

Check this out: [The useState set method is not reflecting a change immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/the-usestate-set-method-is-not-reflecting-a-change-immediately)

Comment: Oh my god, I'm such a fool. I have no idea useState is asynchronous. Thank you for your explanation.

Comment: wait, really?? I thought it changed immediately in the execution context but were batched together for a single rerender. TIL.